# Can not access property from mapDispatchToProps

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux, react-redux

I can not access property from `mapDispatchToProps`, when I use `this.props.updateCar(car)` it says:

> Property 'updateCar' does not exist on type 'Readonly &
>   Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'

Here is my code:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { RootState } from "src/reducers";
import { updateCar } from "src/Car/actions";
import { CarState } from "src/Car/reducers";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

const mapStateToProps = (state: RootState) => ({
  car: state.car
});

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: any) => ({
  updateCar: (car: CarState) => dispatch(updateCar(car))
});

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapStateToProps>;
type MapDispatchToProps = typeof mapDispatchToProps;

type Props = StateProps & MapDispatchToProps;

class CarContainer extends React.Component<Props> {
  updateCar = () => {
    const car: CarState = {
      price: 1,
      name: "Mercedes"
    };
    this.props.updateCar(car);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.props.car.name}
        <button onClick={this.updateCar}>UPDATE</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect<StateProps, MapDispatchToProps>(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(CarContainer);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the `ReturnType<typeof mapDispatchToProps>` the same way you've used it for the `StateProps`

Comment: OK nice :). Thanks

Comment: It would be nice if you mark the answer as the correct answer, so other people will be able to benefit as well :)

Comment: You code seems fine, so I can only assume it comes from your reducer/action creator.